# Postgres updating fields with same value

Tags: postgresql

I have a table as below

| name | item | inum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| na1 | k1 | 5 |
| na2 | k1 | 6 |
| na3 | k2 | 7 |
| na4 | k3 | 7 |
| na5 | k3 | 8 |

If 2 item has the same value, then their inum needs to updated with the highest value
eg,
k1 has 2 rows(na1 and2) with different inum. I need to update inum of na1 with 6 since it is the highest among the 2 k1 inums. Same with k3 as well

| name | item | inum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| na1 | k1 | 6 |
| na2 | k1 | 6 |
| na3 | k2 | 7 |
| na4 | k3 | 8 |
| na5 | k3 | 8 |

Can anyone suggest a postgres code for the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can phrase your query like you phrased your description: tell `update` that each row has to use the highest `inum` it can find of the same `item`. [Demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gDLiCW0r):

```sql
update test t                  --tell `update`
set inum=                      --that each row has to use
   (select max(inum) from test --the highest `inum` it can find
    where item=t.item)         --of the same `item`
returning *;                   --(and show what's changed)
```

| name | item | inum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| na1 | k1 | 6 |
| na2 | k1 | 6 |
| na3 | k2 | 7 |
| na4 | k3 | 8 |
| na5 | k3 | 8 |

That's a correlated [scalar subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES). The [`returning`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.183.7) clause is there only to show what it did.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation as well. I used the above query and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to do that and one is to use the lateral join. ie:

```
select t1.name, t1.item, x.inum 
  from myTable t1, 
  lateral (select max(inum) from myTable t2 where t1.item=t2.item) x(inum);
```

[DBfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/HsnjuVWz)

Another one is to group by and then join. ie:

```
select t1.name, t1.item, t2.maxinum 
  from myTable t1
  inner join
  (select item,max(inum) as maxinum from myTable group by item) t2 
     on t1.item=t2.item;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/rCPaeEPg)

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it using a subquery to find the highest inum value for each item. Then updating the inum column for all rows where the inum value is less than the highest inum value for the corresponding item

```
UPDATE your_table t1
SET inum = (
    SELECT MAX(inum)
    FROM your_table t2
    WHERE t2.item = t1.item
)
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM your_table t3
    WHERE t3.item = t1.item
    HAVING MAX(t3.inum) <> t1.inum
);
```

Hope it helps :)